# Why did Sergeant Dignam provoke Billy Costigan so much?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-departed

Why did Sergeant Dignam provoke Billy Costigan so much in [*The Departed* (2006)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407887/)?

I mean both Colin and Sergeant Dignam attended an interview for a
state trooper. But Sergeant Dignam provokes only Billy Costigan so much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [**How to Ask**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward as to what he is asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dignam (Wahlberg) and Sullivan (Damon) were both Staff Sergeants.  Costigan (DiCaprio) was merely a Trooper.  Why would Dignam provoke Sullivan?  They're the same rank.  Also, Dignam had to outwardly show a lack of favoritism to Costigan so that no one might guess that Costigan was the mole.

Comment: "outwardly show" To whom? People looking into the office?